# How to program the tree view of directories

Tags: java, android, file

How to program the tree view of directories and files so that the user chooses one?

I have found nothing ralated on same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView library for that.

Comment: Seems to be fine, i'll try it

Comment: If my answer was helpful for you, please upvote it))